# update in sharded environment with JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding

I am trying to update a filed 'Content' of a document in sharded environment. My shard key is 'asset' which is included in the query. But I am getting error saying

> "com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" :
>   "/10.102.10.190:27017" , "err" : "update { q: { $and: [ { asset:
>   \"/1/01/01.m3u8\" }, { recList: \"REC-1-1418208180000-1418208300000\"
>   } ] }, u: { $set: { Content: BinData } }, multi: false, upsert: false
>   } does not contain _id or shard key for pattern { asset: 1 }" , "code"
>   : 61 , "n" : 0 , "shards" : [ ] , "shardRawGLE" : { } , "ok" : 1.0} "

```
    BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("Content", content));

    BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("asset", assetf));
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("recList", recId));
    andQuery.put("$and", obj);       

    WriteResult result = collection.update(andQuery, newDocument);
```

Please help me.

Comment: you can use `db.printShardingStatus()` to check sharding status. And perhaps your query and update statement should need to content shard keys.

Comment: I did that. It says 'asset' as the shard key.

Comment: Drop the `$and`. It's not needed and may be causing your problem. The default is to and together query conditions.

Comment: dropping the $and really worked. Thank a lot.